# Pytest does not find pyYAML in Travis CI tests that have PyPI and conda package dependencies

Tags: python, pip, conda, travis-ci, pyyaml

I am trying to set up automatic testing for [my Python package](https://github.com/valentinaschueller/scriptengine-tasks-ecearth) using Travis CI. My Python package depends on [Iris](https://github.com/SciTools/iris/) as well as other packages such as PyYAML, numpy, etc. It also depends on a PyPI package ([ScriptEngine](https://pypi.org/project/scriptengine)). Now, I would like to set up a Travis CI environment using conda (to install Iris) and pip (to install the PyPI package as well as checking the requirements for PyYAML and numpy). I would then like to install my package using `pip install .`.

To test if this works, I have written one simple Pytest test that imports PyYAML.

I am currently trying to do this using this `.travis.yml` file:

```yaml
language: python
python:
  - "3.6"
  - "3.7"
  - "3.8"
# command to install dependencies
install:
  - sudo apt-get update
  - wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
  - bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
  - source "$HOME/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
  - hash -r
  - conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no
  - conda update -q conda
  # Useful for debugging any issues with conda
  - conda info -a
  - conda env create -f tests/test-environment.yml python=$TRAVIS_PYTHON_VERSION
  - conda activate test-environment
  - conda install pip
  - conda install -c conda-forge iris
  - pip install -r requirements.txt
  - pip install .
# command to run tests
script: pytest
```

Note: This is the first time for me to really work with Travis CI. This script is a mixture of examples from the [Conda docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/use-conda-with-travis-ci.html) as well as the Travis CI docs.

Pytest then fails to import PyYAML (although it gets installed because of the requirements.txt as well as the Iris dependencies):
Here is the confirmation from the logs that it got installed:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyYAML>=5.1 in /home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ece-4-monitoring==0.1.0) (5.3.1)
```

And this is the Error from Pytest:

```
$ pytest

============================= test session starts ==============================

platform linux -- Python 3.7.1, pytest-4.3.1, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0

rootdir: /home/travis/build/valentinaschueller/ece-4-monitoring, inifile:

collected 1 item / 1 errors                                                    

==================================== ERRORS ====================================

_________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_file_handling.py _________________

ImportError while importing test module '/home/travis/build/valentinaschueller/sciptengine-tasks-ecearth/tests/test_file_handling.py'.

Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.

Traceback:

tests/test_file_handling.py:3: in <module>

    import helpers.file_handling as file_handling

helpers/file_handling.py:1: in <module>

    import yaml

E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

=========================== 1 error in 0.12 seconds ============================

The command "pytest" exited with 2.
```

If I try this exact setup using a conda virtual environment locally on my computer, I do not get this problem. Why does this not work on the Travis CI virtual machine?

Comment: pytest is installed in `requirements.txt`, right? For debugging purposes I would change `- script: pytest` to `script: echo $(which pytest) && pytest`  and make sure the path printed is `/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/bin/pytest` - I am not sure whether you have to activate your `test-environment` also in the `- script` part.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! The problem was indeed that pytest was not explicitly mentioned in the `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

As [cel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2272172/cel) suggested in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62166835/pytest-does-not-find-pyyaml-in-travis-ci-tests-that-have-pypi-and-conda-package#comment109948746_62166835): I could fix the problem by explicitly requiring pytest in the `requirements.txt`.

It is not necessary to activate `test-environment` in the script part. However, a very helpful tip was to use `echo $(which pytest) && pytest` instead of just `pytest` to check if pytest is installed at `/home/travis/miniconda/envs/test-environment/bin/pytest`.